# Node js, Mongoose calculate sum and returning multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in mongodb as mentioned below.

```
   { "UserID" : "User1",
    "TaskId" : "Task1",
    "SubTaskID" : "Subtask1",
    "StartDate" : ISODate("2016-02-06T05:00:00Z"),
    "EndDate" : ISODate("2016-02-06T05:00:00Z"),
    "Hours" : 8,  //no of hours worked between StartDate and EndDate on the subtask
    "Department:"DEPT1"; //I can have multiple departments
    "__v" : 0}
```

Now I want to calculate the total number of hours worked between startdate and enddate and the total number of hours entered for that subtask in the department by all members within that duration. My output should look like

```
{
   "TaskId":"TaskId1",
   "UserId":"UserId1",
   "startDate":"2016-02-06",
   "endDate":"2016-02-06",
   "totalHours": 10.0,
   "deptTotalHours":100.0,
   "subtasks": [
   {
      "SubTaskID": "SubTask1",
      "totalHours": 4.0,
      "deptTotalHours":40.0
   }, 
   {
      "SubTaskID": "SubTask2",
      "totalHours": 6.0,
      "deptTotalHours":60.0
    }]
}
```

I have tried with $match,$project and $group but I could not be ble to get the response in the specified format. Can someone please suggest me how to get the response in the above specified format?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, then the "totalHours" is meant to be by selected user? Or is is possibly all users but just the current user in the grouping? Also what then is "deptTotalHours"? Is it just everything else apart from the current user? Or is there some other logic behind which "department(s)" would be selected? Those are the parts of logic missing from your explanation and could do with elaboration in an edit.

Comment: Hi Seven, Thank you very much for your quick response. Please find the clarification below.
                                                                                                                              
totalHours: total number of hours worked on a particular subtask by the selected user with in the duration.
deptTotalHours: total number of hours worked by all the users in the department (including the selected use) on that subtask within the duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following pipeline operation which will give you all the information required for subtask. Then totalHours, deptTotalHours across all subtasks is just sum of records from the sub task result (which you can do it in your application). Rest of the information is available as part of your input itself.

`pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {} // Add criteria based on start and end date, don't include UserID criteria here
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$SubTaskID',
      deptTotalHours: {$sum: '$Hours'},
      totalHours: {$sum: {$cond:[
        {$eq: ['$UserID', inputUserId]},
        '$Hours',
        0.0
      ]}
                  }
    }
  }
];`

Comment: Hi Poorna, Thank you very much for your response. I have implemented the way you suggested but getting the response in the below format. the totalHours field is always returning 0. totalHours: {$sum: {$cond:[
        {$eq: ['$UserID', inputUserId]}

Comment: @Rams Have you initiated the inputUserId with the desired user's id? I have run this pipeline for the sample document given in your question with inputUserId = 'User1' and it returns { "_id" : "Subtask1", "deptTotalHours" : 8, "totalHours" : 8 }

Comment: Hi Poorna, Sorry it was my mistake. I was referring by Department id instead of user id. It is working as expected now. Thank you very much Poorna :)